# Indents inside the Excel cell

Tags: excel

After entering text in the cell Excel has this text depending on its (text) characteristics and the user-defined formatting.
Clarify or give, please, a link to MS documents or articles - how are the indents (in px) of inscribed text from the cell boundaries assigned, how they change depending on the font size, horizontal and vertical alignment, the value of the left or right indent?
Certain formulas are used.

I create Excel files in my C program using a third-party library.
For example, I can calculate the width and height of a row in px. I must calculate the width of the column. Column width = line width + additional pixels.
How can I calculate these additional pixels depending on the formatting I have specified?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

an xlsx file is an xml file inside a zip container with some other bits and bobs - if you change the file extension to .zip you can pull out the .xml and look at it yourself, that might speed things up while you wait for someone with a better answer than mine.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, I expected this answer. But before you look at the .xml file, you need to generate it. I do not form it in Excel, but in my program. To write one cell with text to a file, for example, I have to calculate the width and height of the cell (columns and rows, respectively). These parameters depend on the width and length of the line plus internal indents, which depend on the font size, the value of the left or right indent, etc.
How to get the values of these indents?

Answer (score 0):

[From Ms documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-xls/24fed501-1f2e-435b-a371-ad29a57dba58)  *Indentation level: A measure of the distance between the position of content that is in a cell and the logical left side of the cell. An indentation level is equal to three spaces.*